# Right sidebar scrolls with main content which is annoying when reading help, and it dissapears if the window is narrow

Tags: feature-request

**Help Navigation**

It would be very helpful if the right sidebar scrolled independently from the main content section, at least for the help pages where it is used for navigation.

I just finished reading *every* help page and all the extra scrolling to get back to the currently selected part of the navigation list was annoying.

In help the right sidebar provides help navigation and many topics have many subtopics. When I scroll to read a particularly long content page the sidebar scrolls also. Then when I am done reading I have to scroll back up to see where I am currently in the sidebar list. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) when I finished reading the content the next item in the sidebar is not visible to select.

Another possible solution, which should probably be in-addition-to as opposed to instead-of independent sidebar scrolling, would be to have 'next' and 'prev' buttons at the bottom of the page.

**Window Resizing**

In addition to the scrolling, if the window is made too narrow about 900px then the navigation sidebar disappears with no way to show it. The left sidebar which is less important when reading help doesn't disappear until the window is very narrow, and it correctly show a menu button in the titlebar to allow it to be displayed as an overlay.

Suggested solution:

1. Always show the menu icon for the left sidebar to allow the user to hide it in order to make more room for content and allow the right sidebar to be shown with a narrower window.
2. Allow the content section to shrink to some minimum size before hiding the right sidebar. This is what happens after the right sidebar disappears and before the left sidebar is hidden.
3. Provide a menu icon in the titlebar for the right sidebar to allow hide/show and overlay show when the window is very narrow.

Please provide titlebar icons to allow the user to show/hide the either sidebar as desired, and change the order of handling window resize to 1) shrink content section until minimum allowed size, 2) hide right sidebar, 3) hide left sidebar.